# Why can't they open a stargate from Earth to Destiny?

Tags: stargate, stargate-universe

In *Stargate Universe* I understand that they can't dial from the ship *Destiny* to Earth because they don't have enough power. But why can't they dial from Earth to *Destiny*?

Answer (score 16):

Power plain and simple.  Icarus Base was on a planet full of Naquadria, the unstable cousin to Naquadah, the gate material.  To produce enough power to make the connection they had to use the planet as a giant reactor.  And an unstable one at that.

Dialing back from *Destiny* has the same problems.  The only successful dial home from was by constantly drawing power in from a sun to power the gate and that was unstable.  As for the attempt with the seed ship, we don't know how well it would have worked or how long the gate would stay open.  The two dialings to *Destiny* (Icarus and Lucien Alliance) lasted 5min+, dialing from the sun less, and Wray's comment "Very shortly we will be making an attempt to dial Earth. If a successful connection is made, we will need to move quickly." indicates that the power from both ships would only have powered the gate for a short time before leaving both powerless husks.

Comment: But Destiny is capable of dialling Earth if it was fully powered - in one episode they draw power from another ship into their reserves to achieve this.
>! (before the aliens hidden onboard reverse the process)
Does Destiny have access to more power than can be generated on Earth?

Comment: The Destiny's gate is a later version which was probably much improved. So it might a) use less energy and the Destiny is designed to store huge amounts of energy for intergalactic flight.

Comment: Typo: "And an *unstable stable* one"

Comment: @AaronDigulla destiny's gate is a MUCH, MUCH older gate...

Comment: Also Destiny's gate is only designed for the short hops necessary to resupply through the seeded gates. While it is possible to supercharge it and use it for the long gate to earth. As it is possible to haul a 18-wheeler trailer with a Kia Rio, but the engine may not survive the feat.

Comment: I was under the impression that most of the gate network relied on the gates being in roughly the same (relative) position with regular compensation for galactic drift but a Stargate being moved through open space gets cut off from the network.

Comment: @IG_42, Stargates can be inaccessible when on a ship in hyperspace.  However Destiny and it's non-hyperspace FTL can be dialed while in FTL, but the ship is forced out of FTL.  Whether this is a limit of the FTL stability, or a safety measure was never fully explored on SG:U.  Other than that there is no limit to the position of a Stargate within a galactic network.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the Tau'ri can't dial from Earth to *Destiny* is a lack of power.

Back before the Ancients ascended, *Destiny* was far closer to Earth - far less power was required to create a wormhole stable enough for use.

Now that *Destiny* has been flying through the universe for a million years, the power requirements are astronomical, requiring the Tau'ri to connect the gate to the Naquadria core of P4X-351 - there simply isn't any way to provide the power that the gate would need to create a usable wormhole.

Answer (score -1):

The *Destiny* gate was designed well before the other Stargates. As we know, they later modified the gates to have 9 chevrons so that they could actually dial *Destiny*.

Comment: Do you have any references to back up this up?  It would greatly improve the quality of your answer.